# Merging two DEMs of different resolutions

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, dem, merge

I have two sets of GeoTIFFs (or ArcGrids) one at 2m resolution and another at 1m.

I would like to merge the 1m on top of the 2m, coverage varies over the datasets as seen here for example:

2m coverage:

[image]

1m coverage:

[image]

In GeoServer I could create a layer group and have the 1m on top but it will still have to process both datasets i think.

`gdal_merge` could be an option but not sure what syntax for both source folders.

Is there another method I could use?

Comment: Would it be OK to have a 1 m resolution dataset that covers the whole area even some of the pixels comes from the 2 m data? That would waste space compared to the layer group solution.

Comment: Dont you have access to the folders or what is the problem when you try gdal_merge?

Answer (score 1):

The layer groups seems the straightforward approach.

Another possibility is to setup an image mosaic, add an attribute in the index to indicate the resolution, and then force a sort on it with the parameters showing in the layer page.
That would still make the code process both layers though, until some funding lands that allows jai-ext developers to [address this ticket](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/issues/151).